# i have send message with return redirect route with message but not show blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-blade

message not show in blade file.    my controller                     return redirect('login')->with('message', 'please enter a valid user name and password');        my blade file   @if(session('message'))               <div class="alert alert-danger">{{session('message')}}</div>             @endif   route  Route::get('/login',[AuthController::class,'login'])->name('login');`your text`

Answer (score 0):

change

@if(session('message'))

`<div class="alert alert-danger">`
{{session('message')}}`</div>`

@endif

to

@if(\session::has('message'))`<div class="alert alert-danger">`

{{!! \session::get('message') !!}}`</div>`

@endif